# Ruby on rails: previous url helper for entire application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rails-routing, helpermethods

Is there an easy way to write a helper method to always update the previously visited url in the session. I have tried the method below but the url saved is always the current one. I would like to be able to use this helper in all my controllers for redirect.

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :my_previous_url

def my_previous_url
    session[:previous_url] = request.referrer
  end

helper_method :my_previous_url
end
```

I have used it in my update method in the User controller as seen below but it always redirects to the same opened url (kind of looks like refresh was hit).

```
def update
    if current_user.admin == true and @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to my_previous_url, notice: "Password for User #{@user.username} has Successfully been Changed."
      return
    elsif current_user.admin == false and @user.update(user_params)
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to login_path, notice: "Password for User #{@user.username} has Successfully been Changed. Please Log-In Using the New Password."
      return
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
    changed = true
        format.html { redirect_to logout_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.referer isn't what you want here as it will be set on page redirects, thus losing the page you came from originally.  I think that you have an implied requirement that it should return the last visited url which was **different** to the current one, is that the case?  Also, i think that you would only want to set it for GET requests, otherwise you risk sending people back to the wrong url, since they will be sent back with a GET request.  I'm assuming here that the purpose of this previous_url is to give people a "back" link.

Also, don't get the method to set the previous_url mixed up with the method to read it back out again.

I would do it like this:

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_previous_url
  helper_method :previous_url

  def set_previous_url
    if request.method == :get && session[:previous_url] != session[:current_url]
      session[:previous_url] == session[:current_url]
      session[:current_url] = request.url          
    end 
  end

  def previous_url
    session[:previous_url]
  end
end
```

Comment: What i want to accomplish is that users can change their password from the home page, a form will display to edit the password. Also that same edit form can be accessed by admins from another page. I would like to redirect each person back to their original accessing page after submitting or canceling the form. I have tried your code and my page still just refreshes. So my idea is i need to know from where users accessed the form and the only way i can think of is the previous url method.